# iOS - Best Approach to Design Custom UITextField with Transparent Background

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, core-graphics, uibezierpath

[image]

I have to create a textfield given in above image. This text field will be used in the entire app within `UITableViewCell` and `UIView`. What could be the best approach for this?.

So far I think `UIBezierPath` is the last option.

Comment: If your designer can give you a transparent image with the border you could set the background property of the textfield with that image.

Comment: Drawing that using code shouldn't be that difficult, I assume you are weary of this because you haven't done it before? but if you do a bit of reading on the drawing tools available I think you'd find its quite straight forward

Comment: @LoVo i think he needs a transparent textfield instead of setting background image for it

Comment: I already made pretty good experiences with transparent images and borders for all kinds of views, as long as the designer know what he is doing it would have the same effect but with much less programming effort.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: I have created it with UIBezierPath's addLine() and addCurve() functions. it's working but hope some better solution

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question, I really like the design of that UITextField, so I've implemented it in a class. I've made it all @IBDesignable and @IBInspectable

[image: AMTitledTextField]

That's the code:

```
//
//  AMTitledTextField.swift
//
//  Created with  by Alessandro Manilii on 29/11/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 Alessandro Manilii. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class AMTitledTextField: UITextField {

    // MARK: - IBInspectables
    @IBInspectable var title: String = "" {
        didSet { self.updateTextViewBorder() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var titleColor: UIColor = UIColor.black {
        didSet { updateTextViewBorder() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet { updateTextViewBorder() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = UIColor.clear {
        didSet { updateTextViewBorder() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet { updateTextViewBorder() }
    }

    @IBInspectable var placeholderColor: UIColor = .lightGray {
        didSet { setValue(placeholderColor, forKeyPath: "_placeholderLabel.textColor") }
    }

    // MARK: - Properties
    private var borderLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    private var sidePadding: CGFloat = 8.0
    private let verticalPadding: CGFloat = 12.0
    private var lblTitle: UILabel?

    var originNew: CGPoint {
        get { return CGPoint(x: cornerRadius + borderWidth/2, y: 0) }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateTextViewBorder()
    }
}

extension AMTitledTextField {

    func updateTextViewBorder() {
        borderStyle = .none
        createTitle()
        borderLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        borderLayer = nil
        borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        guard let borderLayer = borderLayer else { return }
        borderLayer.path = createPath().cgPath
        borderLayer.strokeColor = borderColor.cgColor
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = borderWidth
        self.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
}

// MARK: - Rectangles Setup
extension AMTitledTextField {

    var fullSidePadding : CGFloat { return cornerRadius + sidePadding }
    var topPadding      : CGFloat { return verticalPadding/2 }
    var textPadding     : CGFloat {return sidePadding/2}

    override public func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: topPadding,
                                                  left: fullSidePadding + textPadding,
                                                  bottom: 0,
                                                  right: fullSidePadding))
    }

    override public func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: topPadding,
                                                  left: fullSidePadding + textPadding,
                                                  bottom: 0,
                                                  right: fullSidePadding))
    }

    override public func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: topPadding,
                                                  left: fullSidePadding + textPadding,
                                                  bottom: 0,
                                                  right: fullSidePadding))
    }

    override public func borderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0,
                                                  left: fullSidePadding + textPadding,
                                                  bottom: 0,
                                                  right: fullSidePadding))
    }
}

private extension AMTitledTextField {

    func setPlaceholderColor(_ color: UIColor) {
        var placeholderText = ""
        if let placeholder = self.placeholder {
            placeholderText = placeholder
        }

        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: placeholderText, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])
    }

    func createTitle() {
        lblTitle = nil
        lblTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: originNew.x, y: originNew.y, width: 25, height: 25))
        guard let lblTitle = lblTitle else { return }

        lblTitle.textAlignment = .center
        lblTitle.text = title
        lblTitle.textColor = titleColor
        lblTitle.font = font
        if let fontSize = font?.pointSize {
            lblTitle.font = lblTitle.font.withSize(fontSize * 0.85)
        }

        lblTitle.sizeToFit()
        lblTitle.frame = CGRect(x: lblTitle.frame.origin.x + sidePadding, y: lblTitle.frame.origin.y, width: lblTitle.frame.width + sidePadding, height: lblTitle.frame.height);
        addSubview(lblTitle)
    }

    func createPath() -> UIBezierPath  {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        guard let lblTitle = lblTitle else { return path }

        let pointA = CGPoint(x: originNew.x + lblTitle.frame.width + sidePadding, y: lblTitle.center.y)
        let pointB = CGPoint(x: frame.width - cornerRadius - borderWidth/2, y: pointA.y)
        let centerUR = CGPoint(x: pointB.x, y: pointA.y + cornerRadius)
        let pointC = CGPoint(x: frame.width - borderWidth/2, y: frame.height - cornerRadius - borderWidth/2)
        let centerBR = CGPoint(x: centerUR.x, y: frame.height - cornerRadius - borderWidth/2)
        let pointD = CGPoint(x: cornerRadius + borderWidth/2, y: frame.height - borderWidth/2)
        let centerBL = CGPoint(x: pointD.x, y: centerBR.y)
        let pointE = CGPoint(x: borderWidth/2, y: centerUR.y)
        let centerUL = CGPoint(x: centerBL.x, y: centerUR.y)
        let pointF = CGPoint(x: pointD.x + sidePadding, y: pointA.y)

        path.move(to: pointA)
        path.addLine(to: pointB)
        path.addArc(withCenter: centerUR, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(3 * Double.pi/2), endAngle: 0, clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: pointC)
        path.addArc(withCenter: centerBR, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/2), clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: pointD)
        path.addArc(withCenter: centerBL, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/2), endAngle: CGFloat(2 * Double.pi/2), clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: pointE)
        path.addArc(withCenter: centerUL, radius: cornerRadius, startAngle:  CGFloat(2 * Double.pi/2), endAngle:  CGFloat(3 * Double.pi/2), clockwise: true)
        path.addLine(to: pointF)

        return path
    }
}
```